# Efficient and stable QR factorization of partially orthonormal matrix

Tags: numerics, matrix-factorization, numerical-limitations, orthogonality, qr

Let $U \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n_U}$ be an orthonormal matrix, let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n_A}$, and $m \geq n_U + n_A$. I want to compute a QR factorization $X = \left[U A\right] = QR$, with $Q \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times (n_U + n_A)}$ and $R \in \mathbb{C}^{(n_U+n_A) \times (n_U+n_A)}$, taking advantage of the orthonormality of $U$.

I am concerned with numerical stability and efficiency. I don't want to just project out $U$ from $A$ and QR the residual because that is equivalent to classical Gram-Schmidt using the basis $U$ on each column of $A$. Is there a way to do this in LAPACK without resorting to a full-size QR of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

Just a long-comment sketched answer. Projecting out $U$ from $A$ and QR the residual is *not* equivalent to classical Gram-Schmidt, I think. You apply orthogonal transformations from the left, not triangular transformations from the right. In particular, because you apply orthogonal transformations, it should be backward stable.

Comment: Let's verify this. Let $\tilde{A}=A - U (U^H A)$. Let $\tilde{a}_j$ be the $j$th column of $\tilde{A}$. Then $\tilde{a}_j = a_j - \sum_{i} (u_i^H a_j) u_i$. Is that not CGS? The inner product in the $i$th element of the sum is computed against the original vector $a_j$ rather than the result of projecting out the previous $u_i$'s as would be done in modified GS.

Comment: It is also very possible that I am misunderstanding the numerical breakdown mechanism in CGS and misapplying it here.

Comment: I must admit that the details of the numericali issues in CGS are not 100% clear to me either. But to me it seems that this is no more similar to CGS than MGS, since the $u_i$ are unchanged by the orthogonalization process. This should show that the angles between $U$ and $\hat{A}$ stay small, which (if I understand correctly) is the concern here.